# try to submit new version ios app, but always reports error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I try to do as instruction at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1830/_index.html

but it looks like useless.

always reports the same error.

your comment welcome

[image]

Comment: To ask a very obvious question, do you have the required signing assets?

Comment: Welcome to provisioning profiles world.

Comment: I recreated the provisioning profile and redownload it, also redownload the ios certificates, but same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract from: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html

No Matching Signing Identity or Provisioning Profiles Found
If a warning message and Fix Issue button appear below the Team pop-up menu in the General pane or in a section of the Capabilities pane in the project editor, read the message and click the Fix Issue button. Xcode may present a series of dialogs asking for more information. For example, a dialog might ask you to select a team for your project, request your development certificate, or register a device. Xcode needs these assets to create your team provisioning profile. If Xcode doesn’t resolve the issue, first follow all the steps in Configuring Identity and Team Settings to verify your project configuration.

For iOS apps, connect a device you want to use for development to your Mac and choose it from the Scheme toolbar menu before clicking Fix Issue. (Xcode automatically registers connected devices selected from this menu.) If the device appears in the ineligible list in the menu, read Your iOS Device Isn’t Listed or Is Ineligible in the Scheme Toolbar Menu.

Read The Private Key for Your Signing Identity Is Missing if you’re missing a private key in your keychain.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to update your Developer ID information. In Xcode:

1. `Preferences` menu
2. `Account` tab
3. select `Apple ID` and evtl. developer program
4. hit `View Details`button at the bottom right
5. hit the refresh button at the bottom left.